# Resharper quick-fix templates

Tags: c#, resharper

Is there a way to change the code generated by a quick-fix in Resharper?  It doesn't seem to be in the live templates.

I'd like  the 'Create Property' quickfix for an unrecognized symbol to generate

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Instead of:

```
protected int MyProperty
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot define quick-fix behavior in Resharper.  However, there are several options for what gets put inside the property body.  Go to Resharper->Options->Languages->Common->Generated members - there are 3 options,

1) throw new NotImplemenatedException()  [your example]

2) Return default value

```
protected int MyProperty
{
    get { return 0; }
    set { }
}
```

3) Not Compiled code

```
protected int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
    ???
    }
    set
    {
    ???
    }
}
```

2 is close to what you're looking for, but still not exactly.

I'd suggest instead using the "prop" Live Template - it will generate exactly what you're looking for, except that it won't do it automagically on an unrecognized symbol.

Comment: Thanks!  I was afraid that was the answer.  VS 2008 will actually do exactly what I want with it's own quick fix-like menu, but I don't know what the keyboard shortcut is to trigger the menu, and I'm so used to doing everything with resharper.  Oh well.